# How the argument principle is used in proof of Rouche's Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

The argument theorem states:

If f is meromorphic in an open set containing a circle C and its interior and if f has no poles and never vanishes in C, then the number of zeros of f inside C minus the number of poles of  inside C is equal to $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$

Rouche's Theorem:

If functions $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in an open set containing a circle $C$ and its interior, and if $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ for all $z \in C$, then $f(z)$ and $f(z)+g(z)$ have the same number of zeros within the circle $C$.

Then in the proof of Rouche's theorem we can assume that $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in an open set containing a circle $C$ and its interior, and $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ for all $z \in C$.

Now here is where we need to apply the argument principle: We know that f is meromorphic (because all holomorphic functions are meromorphic) and we know that f never vanishes on C (because $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ for all $z \in C$), but **how do we know that there are no poles on C?**

Also, the next line of the proof in my textbook states that by the argument principle the number of zeros in C=$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$. Why is it not the number of zeros minus the number of poles? By this point we should have shown that there are no poles on C, but **are there also no poles inside of C?**

Any guidance is helpful.

Comment: Have a look at the condition. It's assuming $f$ and $g$ are **holomorphic** in and on $C$.

Comment: I've been struggling to find a solid understanding of how that helps. Is a holomorphic function without poles, whereas a meromorphic function is a function that is holomorphic everywhere except at its poles?

Comment: If a function is said to be holomorphic in a certain region, then we say it possesses no poles there. On the other hand, if a function is said to be meromorphic in a certain region, then it may possess poles in the region.